# How many Star Destroyer hulks are there on or around Jakku?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

We know of at least two different ones on Jakku in canon - the Inflictor Imperial-class Star Destroyer (the upright one) and the Ravager Executor-class Super Star Destroyer (the upside down one that the Millennium Falcon flies through).

In canon, are there any more we know about that were lost at the Battle of Jakku that probably ended up on the surface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### ## Update ##

**At least 5, and probably more**

The in-universe journal "[Rey's Survival Guide](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rey's_Survival_Guide)" offers the following information

> Imperial Star Destroyers: These huge ships were the main battleships
>   of the Empire and **most were torn to pieces by the time they came down
>   on Jakku. The ones that landed top-down are pretty much demolished,
>   but you'll find others sitting pretty much upright on the sand.**

By definition, there need to be at least two that landed top-down (in order to be referred to in terms of multiples) and at least three other (since we already know of two).

---

<s>Within the main canon (books, films, games, comics) there's no mention of any other Star Destroyers on the surface of Jakku.</s> The '[Journey to the Force Awakens: Lost Stars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Stars)' book makes a clear reference to there being a *fleet* in orbit of Jakku (and in an earlier passage vaguely indicates that there are more than two Star Destroyers in said fleet) <s>but **the only crashed ships we see on the surface, or hear about on the surface** are the two SD's that you've already mentioned in your original question; The [Inflictor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Inflictor) and the [Ravager](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ravager_(Super_Star_Destroyer))</s>

> *“We’re headed toward a major standoff with the rebels,” he said.
>   “**We’re committing a fair portion of the fleet, and if the damned
>   Rebellion wants to stand a chance of keeping that sector, they’ll have
>   to do the same.** This promises to be the largest battle since Endor.”
>   His long finger jabbed at the controls, and an image of a planet in
>   brown, russet, and gold hovered above the holo-projector. “Here we
>   have the desert world of Jakku—worthless on its own but soon to live
>   forever in history as the place where the Empire defeated the
>   Rebellion once and for all.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Lost Stars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Stars)</sup></sub>

The fates of the other (unnnamed, and possibly not even present) Star Destroyers  at the [Battle of Jakku](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Jakku) is an unknown. <s>Presumably they were destroyed in orbit or fled when it became clear that their command ships were lost.</s>